# Filter only user based polymorphic relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am facing one problem. I have such structure:

accounting_journals table has morphed types of deposits, margins etc... all of those morphed types belongs to a user.

I need to retrieve the only user-based accounting_journals note that there is no user_id column on the accounting_journals table it has a relation only on morphed types.

so how can I filter only user-based accounting_journals?

any help would be **appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

As there are different models queried, I would do multiple requests. Example for Deposits:

```
Deposists::query()->whereHas('users', function ($query) {
           $query->where('users.id', 1);
        })->with(['accountingJournals']);
```

Do the same for all related models, then using collection helpers:

- get only accountingJournals
- merge them, unique them
- you have all accountingJournals for a given user

Another way would be to create hasManyTrough relationships, like "users hasMany accountingJournals trough Deposists". But I believe that it would also require 1 query per related model.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but need to get all available user accounting_journals in one relation call. I need that for laravel nova, I have a user table and inside users, I should list all account transactions for specific user.

Comment: and that method should return relation instance not a collection of items